# How to connect a Socket test with aws ec2 by Destination Ip and Port no

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot

I am trying to send the data I receive to my computer into AWS; I use a socket to test for communication. How can I configure the EC2 and make the data received in AWS?

Comment: I have set the inbound rule with the port which is configured in the server and it starts working

Answer (score 0):

I have set the inbound rule with the port which is configured in the server and it starts working